# Migration cakephp 2.x to 3.x grouped result from query

Tags: cakephp, formatting, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

I coded a while with cakephp2. I uses a table with calculated values per year and month.
e.g.

```
YEAR | MONTH | VALUENAME | VALUE 
2011 | 1     | value1    | 100
2011 | 2     | value1    | 120
2011 | 1     | value2    | 1234
2011 | 2     | value2    | 4342
etc.
```

Now I want to have the yearly sum values per 'valuename'.
In Cake2 I used the following expression to get the result, where I got the year as array-key (which is important for my view):

```
$yearvalues = $this->Aggregation->find('list', [
"fields" => ['Aggregation.value_name', 'Aggregation.sum_value', 'Aggregation.y'],
"group" => ['Aggregation.y', 'Aggregation.value_name']
]);
```

In my Model 'Aggregation' I got the following:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
        'sum_value' => "sum(value)",
    );
```

The result is looking as follows:

```
Array
(
    [2011] => Array
        (
            [value1] => 1429.00
            [value2] => 1180.00
            [value3] => 0.00
            [value4] => 804.00
        )

    [2012] => Array
        (
            [value1] => 1878.00
            [value2] => 2793.00
            [value3] => 3900.00
            [value4] => 1606.00
        )
    ...
)
```

How do I get the same result now in Cake3. I'm a little bit confused about how to treat the Query-Object in the right way :-(
That's what I got up to now:

```
$yearvalues->select(['Aggregation.value_name', 
'sum_value' => $yearvalues->func()->sum('Aggregation.value'), 'y'])
->group(['Aggregation.y', 'Aggregation.value_name']);
```

Can someone help me with the right approach?

thx
Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `list` finder for this in CakePHP 3.x too, it supports similar options.

```
$yearvalues
    ->find('list', [
        'keyField' => 'value_name',
        'valueField' => 'sum_value',
        'groupField' => 'y'
    ])
    ->select([
        'Aggregation.value_name', 
        'sum_value' => $yearvalues->func()->sum('Aggregation.value'),
        'Aggregation.y'
    ])
    ->group([
        'Aggregation.y',
        'Aggregation.value_name'
    ]);
```

The `list` finder basically just adds a result formatter that will use `Collection::combine()` to format the retrieved results, which is also why you do not use aliases for the field options, in the results there will only be entities/arrays with properties/field name indices!

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Finding Key/Value Pairs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs)**
- **[Cookbook > Collections > Iterating > Collection::combine()](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::combine)**